# GCP CloudSQL (PostgreSQL) Crash During Stored Procedure Execution and Failover

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a stored procedure in GCP CloudSQL (PostgreSQL v9.0.23). It works find in lower environments; but when it runs in Production (with significantly more volume), it crashes the DB itself which results in a Failover.

When we checked the metrics, what we found out is that the memory is more than 90% just before it crashes (15 GB out of the 16GB instance memory). Also the Read / Writes are very high >1000 Ops per second.

The SP does some select and insert statements. Any suggestions to improve this situation helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a debugging step, try resizing to an instance 2x as large. If the problem goes away, that might be the simplest solution. If the problem repeats then you have a bug. Without details, who knows?

Comment: yes John, thanks for your answer. Please see my response below - we resolved the isse by refactring the query.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that the Cloud SQL instance is running smoothly with a small amount of workload but crashing with the Production environment where more intensive workloads are there, it seems the issue is with the instance size. So I would suggest you increase the instance size as per your need.

Also you have mentioned that the memory usage is 15 GB out of 16 GB which amounts to nearly 94%. As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/operational-guidelines#memory-overloaded) your Cloud SQL instance will not be covered under Cloud SQL SLA if memory usage is over 90% for more than 6 hours of duration. So I would suggest you keep the memory usage within 90%. Also I would suggest keeping the CPU utilization as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/cpu-utilization#recommended-max). To know when your instance reaches any threshold I will suggest you set a monitoring alert for that metrics as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/monitor-instance#system-memory-stackdriver-alert).

If increasing your instance size doesn’t help I would recommend you to create a support ticket with Google Cloud Support so that they can investigate in detail.

Comment: Thanks Prabir. Did not know about the SLA details before. We resolved the issue by refactoring the SP - added "WITH" clause for many sub queries. It was executing repeatedly and ending up in the crash. Once we added "WITH" clause, the memory usage came down to less than 1 GB. Yes, this solution you cannot propose as I have not posted the SP code anywhere. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Great ! Nice to hear your issue got resolved.